# unable to add to ordered set

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm just getting into coreData and am attempting to work with ordered sets. I am confused why the object is not getting added to the ordered set. I want to add the object to self.project.toEntries.

here is a screenShot: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3S1O.png

```
- (void)addEntryWithStartDate
{
Entry *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:newEntry inManagedObjectContext:[TTStack sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];

NSMutableArray *mutableEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.project.toEntries array]];
[mutableEntries addObject:entry];
NSOrderedSet *orderdedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:mutableEntries];
self.project.toEntries = orderdedSet;

entry.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

[self save];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `self.project`, whatever that may be, is `nil`. You have never assigned any object to this property.

Comment: Thank you. I was misunderstanding properties.

Comment: You might be happier learning Swift, which would have prevented you from making this mistake.